# Returning null as an int permitted with ternary operator but not if statement

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, conditional-operator, autoboxing

Let's look at the simple Java code in the following snippet:

```
public class Main {

    private int temp() {
        return true ? null : 0;
        // No compiler error - the compiler allows a return value of null
        // in a method signature that returns an int.
    }

    private int same() {
        if (true) {
            return null;
            // The same is not possible with if,
            // and causes a compile-time error - incompatible types.
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        System.out.println(m.temp());
        System.out.println(m.same());
    }
}
```

In this simplest of Java code, the `temp()` method issues no compiler error even though the return type of the function is `int`, and we are trying to return the value `null` (through the statement `return true ? null : 0;`). When compiled, this obviously causes the run time exception `NullPointerException`.

However, it appears that the same thing is wrong if we represent the ternary operator with an `if` statement (as in the `same()` method), which *does* issue a compile-time error! Why?

Comment: Also, `int foo = (true ? null : 0)` and `new Integer(null)` both compile fine, the second being the explicit form of autoboxing.

Comment: @Izkata the problem here is for me to understand why the compiler is trying to autobox `null` to `Integer`... That would look just like "guessing" to me or "making things work"...

Comment: ...Huhm, I thought I had an answer there, as the Integer constructor (what the docs I found say is used for autoboxing) is allowed to take a String as an argument (which can be null).  However, they also say that the constructor acts identically to the method parseInt(), which would throw a NumberFormatException upon getting passed a null...

Comment: @Izkata - the String argument c'tor for Integer is not an autoboxing oepration. A String can't be autoboxed to an Integer. (The function `Integer foo() { return "1"; }` won't compile.)

Comment: Cool, learned something new about the ternary operator!

Comment: Also worth noting: `return (Integer)null;` compiles fine

Comment: \o\ Yay to the Runtime NullPointerExceptions /o/ Intriguing question tho, I wonder if will these things be ever changed. like `public void foo() { try { foo(); } finally { foo(); } }` being a nearly endless recursive function.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The compiler interprets `null` as a null reference to an `Integer`, applies the autoboxing/unboxing rules for the conditional operator (as described in the [Java Language Specification, 15.25](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)), and moves happily on. This will generate a `NullPointerException` at run time, which you can confirm by trying it.

Comment: Given the link to the Java Language Specification that you posted, which point do you think gets executed in the case of the question above? The last one (since I'm still trying to understand `capture conversion` and `lub(T1,T2)`)?? Also, Is it really possible to apply boxing to a null value? Wouldn't this be like "guessing"??

Comment: ´@Gevorg A null pointer is a valid pointer to every possible object so nothing bad can happen there. The compiler just assumes that null is an Integer which it then can autobox to int.

Comment: @Gevorg - See nowaq's comment and my response to his post. I think he picked the correct clause. `lub(T1,T2)` is the most specific reference type in common in the type hierarchy of T1 and T2. (They both share at least Object, so there is always a most specific reference type.)

Comment: @TedHopp I analyzed `lub(T1,T2)` a lot (see my comments all around and my answer below). I thought the answer was in there as well but I changed my mind since I do not believe that `null` can be boxed to anything. Explicit boxing of `null` to `Integer` -`new Integer(null);` would throw a `NumberFormatException` and this does not happen.

Comment: @Gevorg - `null` is not _boxed_ into an Integer, it is _interpreted_ as a reference to an Integer (a null reference, but that's not a problem). No Integer object is constructed from the null, so there's no reason for a NumberFormatException.

Comment: @TedHopp I see you're point of view but looking at the JLS that you posted: `Let T1 be the type that results from applying boxing conversion to S1` still makes me think that the JVM applies boxing to `null`. Maybe this is not the case to look at though..

Comment: @Gevorg - If you look at the [rules for boxing conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#190697), and apply them to `null` (which is not a primitive numeric type), the applicable clause is "If _p_ is a value of any other type, boxing conversion is equivalent to an identity conversion". So boxing conversion of `null` to `Integer` yields `null`, without invoking any `Integer` constructor.

Comment: It seems to me that what is actually happening here is that the compiler only goes as far as the boxing conversion of both, to get a null Int and a zero Int.  But unboxing a null throws a null-pointer exception, so **when it tries to unbox the null Int at run time**, it gets that error.  This is probably what you are saying.  Saying "autoboxing/unboxing" makes it sound like both happened at compile here, but I think you were just referring to the rules in general which include both things, but only boxing happens for the code above.

Comment: @Anon316 - Actually, both the boxing and unboxing conversions happen at run time. For the ternary operator, the compiler either pushes `null` to the stack directly or else pushes 0 and then calls the static method `Integer.valueOf()` (which replaces the top element on the stack with a reference to an `Integer` object). It then generates bytecode to obtain the return value via an instance method call to `Integer.intValue()` using the presumed `Integer` object reference on the stack. The NPE is triggered when the runtime discovers that the object reference is `null`.

Comment: @TedHopp - yes, both boxing and unboxing happen at runtime, but what happens at compile time.  I read the specs to say that, for this case, only boxing happens - boxing the 0 to Int, and using that to determine the result between null and Int (a reference type) is the reference type Int.

Comment: @Anon316 - Ah, now I understand our discussion. The spec is a bit confusing because it is talking about boxing conversion of _types_, not of values. So when the compiler does a type analysis, it applies a boxing conversion to the null type (not to the value `null`) and to the primitive type `int` (not to the value `0`). The results are the null type (the null type is its own boxing conversion) and the `Integer` reference type. Then the least upper bound of those two types is `Integer`.

Answer (score 40):

I think, the Java compiler interprets `true ? null : 0` as an `Integer` expression, which can be implicitly converted to `int`, possibly giving `NullPointerException`.

For the second case, the expression `null` is of the special *null type* [see](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25-300-A), so the code `return null` makes type mismatch.

Comment: I assume this is related to auto-boxing?  Presumably the first return would *not* compile prior to Java 5, right?

Comment: @Michael that appears to be the case if you set Eclipse's compliance level to pre-5.

Comment: @Michael: this definitely looks like auto-boxing (I'm quite new to Java, and cannot make more defined statement -- sorry).

Comment: @Vlad how would the compiler end up interpreting `true ? null : 0` as `Integer`? By autoboxing `0` first??

Comment: @Gevorg: Look [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25): _Otherwise, the second and third operands are of types S1 and S2 respectively. Let T1 be the type that results from applying boxing conversion to S1, and let T2 be the type that results from applying boxing conversion to S2._ and the following text.

Comment: @Vlad I'm still trying to understand `capture conversion` and `lub(T1,T2)` and I don't understand how the compiler could try to autobox a null value to anything... Wouldn't that be random guessing to "make things work"? The alternative would be autoboxing 0 to Integer first, then we would fall into point 3 of your link, but I'm not sure that this is what's happening here..

Comment: @Gevorg: I think it's autoboxing int `0` to Integer.

Comment: @Vlad right, that would be the last case of the language specification and my best guess as well. But it's hard for me to believe that the compiler would then jump to point 3 since I believe that it should check the different possibilities in order as suggested by those "if, otherwise"... `lub(T1,T2)` is pretty painful to understand for me..

Comment: @Vlad also, if you try to explicitly box `null` to `Integer` with `new Integer(null);` "Let T1 be the type that results from applying boxing conversion to S1..." you would get a `NumberFormatException` and this is not the case.

Comment: @Gevorg: well, I would use `(Integer)null` for explicating the intention: `new Integer(null)` calls the constructor [`Integer(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: @Vlad that's casting and not explicit boxing. Explicit boxing is defined as using the constructor or the valueOf function

Answer (score 32):

Actually, its all explained in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25-300-A).

> The type of a conditional expression is determined as follows:
>
> - If the second and third operands have the same type (which may be the null type), then that is the type of the conditional expression.

Therefore the "null" in your `(true ? null : 0)` gets an int type and then is autoboxed to Integer.

Try something like this to verify this `(true ? null : null)` and you will get the compiler error.

Comment: But that clause of the rules doesn't apply: the second and third operands do _not_ have the same type.

Comment: Then the answer seems to be in the following statement:
> Otherwise, the second and third operands are of types S1 and S2 respectively. Let T1 be the type that results from applying boxing conversion to S1, and let T2 be the type that results from applying boxing conversion to S2. The type of the conditional expression is the result of applying capture conversion (§5.1.10) to lub(T1, T2) (§15.12.2.7).

Comment: I think that's the applicable clause. Then it tries to apply auto-unboxing in order to return an `int` value from the function, which causes a NPE.

Comment: @nowaq I thought this too. However, if you try to explicitly box `null` to `Integer` with `new Integer(null);` "Let T1 be the type that results from applying boxing conversion to S1..." you would get a `NumberFormatException` and this is not the case...

Comment: @Gevorg I'd think since an exception happens when doing the boxing we don't get ANY result here. The compiler is just obliged to generate code that follows the definition which it does - we just get the exception before we're done.

Comment: @Voo - There is no exception generated when boxing anything. The exception happens when _un_boxing the null in order to return an int value from the method. If the method signature were changed to return an Integer, there would be no exception at all -- it would just return `null`.

Answer (score 25):

In the case of the `if` statement, the `null` reference is not treated as an `Integer` reference because it is not participating in an *expression* that forces it to be interpreted as such. Therefore the error can be readily caught at compile-time because it is more clearly a *type* error.

As for the conditional operator, the Java Language Specification §15.25 “Conditional Operator `? :`” answers this nicely in the rules for how type conversion is applied:

> - If the second and third operands have the same type (which may be the null
>     type), then that is the type of the conditional expression.
>     **Does not apply because `null` is not `int`.**
>
> ---
>
> - If one of the second and third operands is of type boolean and the type of the
>     other is of type Boolean, then the type of the conditional expression is boolean.
>     **Does not apply because neither `null` nor `int` is `boolean` or `Boolean`.**
>
> ---
>
> - If one of the second and third operands is of the null type and the type of the
>     other is a reference type, then the type of the conditional expression is that
>     reference type.
>     **Does not apply because `null` is of the null type, but `int` is not a reference type.**
>
> ---
>
> - Otherwise, if the second and third operands have types that are convertible
>     (§5.1.8) to numeric types, then there are several cases: […]
>     **Applies: `null` is treated as convertible to a numeric type, and is defined in §5.1.8 “Unboxing Conversion” to throw a `NullPointerException`.**

Comment: If `0` is autoboxed to `Integer` then the compiler is executing the last case of the "ternary operator rules" as described in the Java Language Specification. If that's true, then it's hard for me to believe that it would then jump to case 3 of the same rules that is having a null and a reference type that make the return value of the ternary operator being the reference type (Integer)...

Comment: @Gevorg - Why is it hard to believe that the ternary operator is returning an `Integer`? That's exactly what's happening; the NPE is being generated by trying to unbox the expression value in order to return an `int` from the function. Change the function to return an `Integer` and it will return `null` with no problem.

Comment: @TedHopp: Gevorg was responding to an earlier revision of my answer, which was incorrect. You should ignore the discrepancy.

Comment: @JonPurdy "A type is said to be convertible to a numeric type if it is a numeric type, or it is a reference type that may be converted to a numeric type by unboxing conversion" and I don't think that `null` falls in this category. Also, we would then go into the "Otherwise, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is applied ... Note that binary numeric promotion performs unboxing conversion (§5.1.8)  ..." step to determine the return type. But unboxing conversion would generate a NPE and this happens only at runtime and not while trying to determine the ternary operator type. I'm still confused..

Comment: @Gevorg: Unboxing happens at runtime. The `null` is treated as though it had type `int`, but is actually equivalent to `throw new NullPointerException()`, that’s all.

Answer (score 11):

The first thing to keep in mind is that Java ternary operators have a "type", and that this is what the compiler will determine and consider no matter what the actual/real types of the second or third parameter are. Depending on several factors the ternary operator type is determined in different ways as illustrated in the [Java Language Specification 15.26](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25-300-E)

In the question above we should consider the last case:

> Otherwise, the second and third operands are of types *S1* and *S2* respectively. Let *T1* be the type that results from applying boxing conversion to *S1*, and let *T2* be the type that results from applying boxing conversion to *S2*. The type of the conditional expression is the result of applying capture conversion (§5.1.10) to *lub(T1, T2)* (§15.12.2.7).

This is by far the most complex case once you take a look at [applying capture conversion (§5.1.10)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10) and most of all at *[lub(T1, T2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.7)*.

In plain English and after an extreme simplification we can describe the process as calculating the "Least Common Superclass" (yes, think of the LCM) of the second and third parameters. This will give us the ternary operator "type". Again, what I just said is an extreme simplification (consider classes that implement multiple common interfaces).

For example, if you try the following:

```
long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
return(true ? new java.sql.Timestamp(millis) : new java.sql.Time(millis));
```

You'll notice that resulting type of the conditional expression is `java.util.Date` since it's the "Least Common Superclass" for the `Timestamp`/`Time` pair.

Since `null` can be autoboxed to anything, the "Least Common Superclass" is the `Integer` class and this will be the return type of the conditional expression (ternary operator) above. The return value will then be a null pointer of type `Integer` and that is what will be returned by the ternary operator.

At runtime, when the Java Virtual Machine unboxes the `Integer` a `NullPointerException` is thrown. This happens because the JVM attempts to invoke the function `null.intValue()`, where `null` is the result of autoboxing.

In my opinion (and since my opinion is not in the Java Language Specification many people will find it wrong anyway) the compiler does a poor job in evaluating the expression in your question. Given that you wrote `true ? param1 : param2` the compiler should determine right away that the first parameter -`null`- will be returned and it should generate a compiler error. This is somewhat similar to when you write `while(true){} etc...` and the compiler complains about the code underneath the loop and flags it with `Unreachable Statements`.

Your second case is pretty straightforward and this answer is already too long... ;)

**CORRECTION:**

After another analysis I believe that I was wrong to say that a `null` value can be boxed/autoboxed to anything. Talking about the class Integer, explicit boxing consists in invoking the `new Integer(...)` constructor or maybe the `Integer.valueOf(int i);` (I found this version somewhere). The former would throw a `NumberFormatException` (and this does not happen) while the second would just not make sense since an `int` cannot be `null`...

Comment: The `null` in OP's original code is not boxed. The way it works is: the compiler assumes that the `null` is a reference to an Integer. Using the rules for ternary expression types, it decides the entire expression is an Integer expression. It then generates code to autobox the `1` (in case the condition evaluates to `false`). During execution, the condition evaluates to `true` so the expression evaluates to `null`. When trying to return an `int` from the function, the `null` is unboxed. That then throws a NPE. (The compiler might optimize most of this away.)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, in the first case the expression can be evaluated, since the compiler knows, that it must be evaluated as an `Integer`, however in the second case the type of the return value (`null`) can not be determined, so it can not be compiled. If you cast it to `Integer`, the code will compile.

Answer (score 2):

```
private int temp() {

    if (true) {
        Integer x = null;
        return x;// since that is fine because of unboxing then the returned value could be null
        //in other words I can say x could be null or new Integer(intValue) or a intValue
    }

    return (true ? null : 0);  //this will be prefectly legal null would be refrence to Integer. The concept is one the returned
    //value can be Integer 
    // then null is accepted to be a variable (-refrence variable-) of Integer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
public class ConditionalExpressionType {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "";
        s += (true ? 1 : "") instanceof Integer;
        System.out.println(s);

        String t = "";
        t += (!true ? 1 : "") instanceof String;
        System.out.println(t);

    }

}
```

The output is true, true.

Eclipse color codes the 1 in the conditional expression as autoboxed.

My guess is the compiler is seeing the return type of the expression as Object.