# Why and how are these two conditionals treated differently by the compiler?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, conditional-operator, type-bounds

The following two code samples represent the same logic. Check to see if a string is null and branch based upon that check. The first sample compiles safely. The second produces a type mismatch error related to Java generics. My question seems simple enough, but it eludes me. Why does the compiler treat these two statements differently? How can I better understand what's going on here?

```
/* compiles cleanly */
protected Collection<String> getUserRoles(Object context,
        Set<String> mappableRoles) {
    String cookieValue = extractCookieValue(context);
    if (cookieValue != null) {
        return securityService.getRolesForUser(cookieValue);
    } else {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
}


/* produces a compiler error */
protected Collection<String> getUserRoles(Object context,
            Set<String> mappableRoles) {
    String cookieValue = extractCookieValue(context);
    return cookieValue == null ? Collections.emptySet()
            : securityService.getRolesForUser(cookieValue);
}
```

The compiler error from Eclipse.

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from Set<capture#1-of ? extends Object> to Collection<String>`

As requested, here's the relevant portion of the SecurityService interface.

```
public interface SecurityService {
    public Set<String> getRolesForUser(String userId);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the signature for securityService.getRolesForUser() please?

Comment: Added. The interface has one more method, but it isn't called from this example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem should reside in how the compiler interprets the return value of the ternary operator. You might want to take a look at [part 15.25 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25) or at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098953/tricky-ternary-operator-in-java-autoboxing/8103083#8103083) (kinda related because it's even further complicated by autoboxing and it throws an error at runtime instead of at compile time).

Hope this puts you on the right direction.

Comment: It looks to me then that the capture conversion process is the culprit then. Most of that documentation is well over my head, but at least I can point to a piece of the generics puzzle. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It's because `Collections.emptySet()` returns an untyped `Set`. Instead, try this:

```
Collections.<String>emptySet()
```

Comment: That does remove the compiler error, but why? I'm most interested in why the type inference can be made from the if/else construct and not the ternary operator.

Comment: Apologies - I missed that part of the question. @Gevorg provides links that explain it much better than I could.

Answer (score 1):

**Collections.emptySet()** is declared as

```
public static final <T> Set<T> emptySet()
```

The first **T** is used for [Type Inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypeinference.html). The second **getUserRoles** implementation is too complex for java compiler to detect right type. That is the reason of the issue. 
Work around:

```
protected Collection<String> getUserRoles(Object context,
            Set<String> mappableRoles) {
    String cookieValue = extractCookieValue(context);
    Collection<String> a = null;
    return cookieValue == null ? a = Collections.emptySet()
            : securityService.getRolesForUser(cookieValue);
}
```