# Java null to int Conditional Operator issue

Tags: java, int, autoboxing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tricky ternary operator in Java - autoboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098953/tricky-ternary-operator-in-java-autoboxing)

We know that `int roomCode = null;` is not allowed by the compiler.

Then why the Code 1 doesn't give a compiler error, when Code 2 does.

Code 1:

```
int roomCode = (childCount == 0) ? 100 : null;
```

Code 2:

```
int roomCode = 0;
if(childCount == 0) roomCode = 100;
else roomCode = null; // Type mismatch: cannot convert from null to int
```

Comment: maybe related to autoboxing but I don't see how...

Comment: What does the `null` evaluate to when it takes that path?

Comment: From the [JLS 15.25](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25): `If one of the second and third operands is of the null type and the type of the other is a reference type, then the type of the conditional expression is that reference type.` So in your case it might consider return type of `?:` operator as int.

Comment: Before I post, I searched but couldn't find a duplicate. Thanx for the reference Joel. +1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did a little debugging and found out that when evaluating

```
(childCount == 0) ? 100 : null;
```

the program calls the method `valueOf` of Integer to evaluate the `null`. It returns an Integer and as an Integer can be null (and not an int), it compiles. As if you were doing something like:

```
int roomCode = new Integer(null);
```

So it is related to autoboxing.