# "Wrong" return type when using if vs. ternary opertator in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, return, ternary-operator

In the following class, the return type of the two methods is inconsistent with the idea that the ternary operator:

```
return condition?a:b;
```

is equivalent to

```
if(condition) {
    return a;
} else{ 
    return b;
}
```

The first returns a Double and the second a Long:

```
public class IfTest {
    public static Long longValue = 1l;
    public static Double doubleValue = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getWithIf().getClass());// outpus Long
        System.out.println(getWithQuestionMark().getClass());// outputs Double
    }

    public static Object getWithQuestionMark() {
        return doubleValue == null ? longValue : doubleValue;
    }

    public static Object getWithIf() {
        if (doubleValue == null) {
            return longValue;
         } else {
            return doubleValue;
        }
    }
}
```

I can imagine this has to do with the compiler narrow casting the return type of `getWithQuestionMark()` but is that language wise ok? It's certainly not what I would have expected.

Any insights most welcome!

Edit: there's very good answers below. Additionally, the following question referenced by  @sakthisundar explores another side effect of the type promotion occurring in the ternary operator: [Tricky ternary operator in Java - autoboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098953/tricky-ternary-operator-in-java-autoboxing)

Comment: Similar type of question has been already asked before and the reason is same as Jon Skeet's answer. Checkout [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098953/tricky-ternary-operator-in-java-autoboxing)

Comment: @sakthisundar thanks! The question you point to is motivated by the same *answer*, but I couldn't find it when starting with the *problem*. I've referenced it directly in the question body now

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basically it's following the rules of [section 15.25 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25), specifically:

> Otherwise, if the second and third operands have types that are convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric types, then there are several cases:
>
> - [...]
> - Otherwise, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is applied to the operand types, and the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the second and third operands.

So [section 5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) is followed, which will basically involves unboxing - so this makes your expression work as if `longValue` and `doubleValue` were of types `long` and `double` respectively, and the widening promotion is applied to the `long` to get an overall result type of `double`.

That `double` is then boxed in order to return an `Object` from the method.

Comment: Aha! So, `1+2` gives an integer, `1+2d` gives a double and likewise the `:` does numeric promotion if possible. Still not what I would have expected, but better than it having anything to do with the return type. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Jon's answer, looking at the bytecode you see:

```
public static java.lang.Object getWithQuestionMark();
  Code:
   0:   getstatic       #7; //Field doubleValue:Ljava/lang/Double;
   3:   ifnonnull       16
   6:   getstatic       #8; //Field longValue:Ljava/lang/Long;
   9:   invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/Long.longValue:()J
   12:  l2d
   13:  goto    22
   16:  getstatic       #7; //Field doubleValue:Ljava/lang/Double;
   19:  invokevirtual   #10; //Method java/lang/Double.doubleValue:()D
   22:  invokestatic    #11; //Method java/lang/Double.valueOf:(D)Ljava/lang/Double;
   25:  astore_0
   26:  aload_0
   27:  areturn
```

Whereas if you tell the compiler that you're not interested in numbers:

```
public static Object getWithQuestionMark() {
    return doubleValue == null ? (Object)longValue : (Object)doubleValue;
}
```

you'll get what you were after (bytecode)

```
public static java.lang.Object getWithQuestionMark();
  Code:
   0:   getstatic       #7; //Field doubleValue:Ljava/lang/Double;
   3:   ifnonnull       12
   6:   getstatic       #8; //Field longValue:Ljava/lang/Long;
   9:   goto    15
   12:  getstatic       #7; //Field doubleValue:Ljava/lang/Double;
   15:  areturn
```

outputs:

```
$ java IfTest
class java.lang.Long
class java.lang.Long
```

Comment: Only a single upcast to `Object` is enough.