# why I can set primitive types to null in ternary operations

Tags: java, null, ternary-operator, raw-types

I always thought that primitive types in Java cannot be `null`, as it is a compile time error if i attempt to do something like this:

```
int test = null;
```

However in a ternary operation, it seems to be allowed:

```
int test = something != 0 ? 5 : null;
```

Isn't a ternary operation just short for (in this case):

```
int test;
if (something != 0){
    test = 5;
} else {
    test = null
}
```

which of course should not be allowed. if that condition fails, It will automaticly throw a `NullPointerException` due to autoboxing. So why the java-compiler doesn't fetch nonsense like this?

Comment: By the way, you're talking about *primitive* types. Raw types are something completely different. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html

Comment: youre right! I just confused them, and changed it accordingly

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tricky ternary operator in Java - autoboxing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098953/tricky-ternary-operator-in-java-autoboxing)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What happens is that the Java compiler first tries to make the types of the expressions on either side of the `:` equal. In this case, it autoboxes the `5` to an `Integer`; note that `null` is a valid value for `Integer`. The result of the whole ternary expression is `Integer`. You assign that to an `int`, so the `Integer` is then autounboxed.

Essentially the compiler applies autoboxing and -unboxing so that the line is going to look like this:

```
int test = (something != 0 ? Integer.valueOf(5) : null).intValue();
```

Indeed, autounboxing `null` leads to a `NullPointerException`.

> So why the java-compiler doesn't fetch nonsense like this?

Because the designers of the Java language defined the language in such a way that it works like this and didn't decide that this has to be treated as an error...

[Section 15.25](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) of the Java Language Specification explains how the type of the whole expression is determined.

Comment: @nhahtdh Why do you think so?

Comment: Sorry, never mind. You are right. It's confusion on my part when reading the disassembled code.