# Does this function call itself or call the overload?

Tags: java, overloading

Consider two overloads:

```
public void add(Integer value)
{
    add(value == null ? null : value.doubleValue());        
}
```

and

```
public void add(Double value)
{
    // some code here
}
```

If I call the first one with a `null` instance of an `Integer`, then does the ternary conditional call the overload to a `Double`, or does it call itself?

On my machine it calls the `Double` overload, but is this well-defined Java? And what does the JLS say about this?

Comment: Have you tried reading the JLS yourself? Seems to me its completely unnecessary to ask what the JLS says when it's available online for free to read yourself. So I suggest that you will find it fruitful to read the JLS yourself. @Fitzwilliam Bennet-Darcy

Comment: Try it yourself! You learn quicker with hands-on experience!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43506017/2513200

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it's well defined that it will call the `Double` overload. It *couldn't* call the `Integer` overload because there's no implicit conversion from `double` (which is the type of the conditional expression) to `Integer`.

Basically, there are two parts of this that are irrelevant:

- That the method is being called from an overload
- That the method argument is a conditional expression

So if you think about it as:

```
Double d = getSomeDoubleValueFromAnywhere();
add(d);
```

... which method would you expect to be called? Presumably the `add(Double)` method - so that's what is called in your situation too.

The tricky part is working out the type of the conditional expression - is it `Double` or `double`? I believe the [rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) (which are hard to follow, IMO) mean that it's `Double`, due to the use of a `null` literal (which is of the `null` type). If instead you had:

```
Double dv = null;
add(value == null ? dv : value.doubleValue());
```

... then the conditional expression type would be `double`, and you'd get a `NullPointerException` if `value` were ever `null`, because it would be trying to unbox the `null` value.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice, and for fixing one of my very many bugs.

Comment: @FitzwilliamBennet-Darcy: My mistake - it wasn't a bug! (There are similar situations where it is though... I'm trying to remember the exact case now...)

Comment: Thankfully I am terribly forgetful. It's a lovely answer all the same.

Comment: Until I read @Andremoniy's link I could not understand why `null` would be evaluated as a `Double`. Could you please add that to your answer?

Comment: Thank you! That is a very good intuitive way to think about it. Here's more fuel for your first million!

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I'm still working on this, as it's not clear whether the type of the conditional expression is actually `double` or `Double`.

Comment: Based on the link provided by @Andremoniy, I think there is only one item that applies: `If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type T, and the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.` That means `Double`.

Comment: Intuitively, you can't have a `double` set to `null`

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Yes, I know that you can't set a `double` to `null`. But the null type *isn't* the result of applying a boxing conversion to `double`. And if it did, it would mean `double`, not `Double` (because `double` is the primitive type).

Comment: You are right. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13291117/2988730. Looks like it's `double` after all.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: No, it's not, it's `Double` - just like the type of the expression in that related question is `Integer`.

Comment: [Table 15.25-B](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) in the JLS says the type of the conditional expression is actually `lub(null,Double)`, where `lub` is some [crazy incomprehensible thing from section 4.10.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.4).

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that such kind of question was already asked here, but can not find it.

Anyway,

`add(value == null ? null : value.doubleValue());` invokes `add(Double value)`, this is very easy to check via trying to compile code w/o second method, and in the debugger.

Regarding what does JLS say about it: type of the expression `value == null ? null : value.doubleValue()` is obviously `Double`, how it is described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25).

Comment: That is one dense list. Thanks for the link.

Comment: You say the type is "obviously `double`" - I'm not sure about that. It's what I originally thought as well, but then that would give a `NullPointerException` if the Integer value were a null reference, and that doesn't seem to happen. I'm still looking into this.

Comment: Having worked through it now, I'm pretty sure that the type of the expression really *is* `Double` rather than `double`.

Comment: @JonSkeet of course it is `Double` due to autoboxing, this is my terrible misprint, thanks for pointing that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098953/tricky-ternary-operator-in-java-autoboxing

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `.doubleValue()`, even if it is a whole number, it is still converted to double. Thus is is calling the overload public void `add(Double value)`.