# What is lub(null, Double)?

Tags: java, types, language-lawyer

[Table 15.25-B](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) in JLS version 8 says that the type of a conditional expression

```
true ? null : 0.0
```

is `lub(null,Double)`, where `lub` appears to be some crazy incomprehensible thing from [section 4.10.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.4).

This appears to be distinct from the `Double` type somehow, or they probably would have just written `Double`, like they did elsewhere in the table. It's not clear what the difference could be, though. I tried to work it out from section 4.10.4, but by the time I got to the part about

> Let lub(U1 ... Uk) be:
>
> Best(W1) & ... & Best(Wr)

it seemed like they were saying that this type is an *intersection type* of the null and Double types, which makes no sense.

What is `lub(null, Double)`? How does a conditional expression with this type behave differently from if its type were just defined as `Double`?

Comment: I think it is just the same as `Double`, like all the `bnp(X, Y)` in the table are not evaluated either.

Comment: @kennytm: Many of those `bnp`s actually can't be collapsed, because they denote [special handling when one operand is a constant expression of type `int`](http://ideone.com/jsisCy). This makes me wary of assuming that the `lub`s can be collapsed.

Comment: This case is denoted as `byte | bnp(int,byte)` in the table, not just `bnp(int, byte)`.

Comment: Yeah, the ones where it just says `bnp(x, y)` instead of `x | bnp(y, z)` seem to be simplifiable to ordinary types, so maybe `lub(null, Double)` does simplify.

Comment: I think I figured out where I went wrong when I was getting `null & Double` for the lub. If my current understanding is correct, the `lub` definition in 4.10.4 does resolve `lub(null, Double)` to `Double`.

Comment: "`lub` appears to be some crazy incomprehensible thing" is a great way to approach something if you don't want to learn it. "lub" is an abbreviation for "least upper bound" and refers to how generic type capture conversions are resolved. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10

Comment: @LewBloch: No, I'm pretty sure it's referring to the thing from 4.10.4. Also, [I already worked through the definition and figured it out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43507503/2357112).

Comment: Ah - good point and better result.

Answer (score 8):

It's just `Double`.

Informally, `lub(null, Double)` is (a decent approximation to) the most specific type that contains all values of the `null` type and the `Double` type, and the most specific such type is `Double`.

Formally, we can work through the definition of `lub` in [JLS section 4.10.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.4), and we find that `lub(null, Double)` is `Double`:

> The least upper bound, or "lub", of a set of reference types is a
>   shared supertype that is more specific than any other shared supertype
>   (that is, no other shared supertype is a subtype of the least upper
>   bound). This type, lub(U1, ..., Uk), is determined as follows.
>
> If k = 1, then the lub is the type itself: lub(U) = U.
>
> Otherwise:
>
> For each Ui (1 ≤ i ≤ k):
>
> Let ST(Ui) be the set of supertypes of Ui.

[ST(null) is the set of all reference types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2), and ST(Double) is {Object, Number, Double}.

> Let EST(Ui), the set of erased supertypes of Ui, be:
>
> EST(Ui) = { |W| | W in ST(Ui) } where |W| is the erasure of W.

EST(null) is the set of the erasures of all reference types, and EST(Double) is {Object, Number, Double}.

> Let EC, the erased candidate set for U1 ... Uk, be the intersection of all the sets EST(Ui) (1 ≤ i ≤ k).

EC is the intersection of EST(null) and EST(Double), so EC is {Object, Number, Double}.

> Let MEC, the minimal erased candidate set for U1 ... Uk, be:
>
> MEC = { V | V in EC, and for all W ≠ V in EC, it is not the case that
>   W <: V }

MEC is the set of all types in EC that have no proper subtype in EC. Double is a proper subtype of both Number and Object, so MEC = {Double}. (`W <: V` means that the type `W` is a subtype of the type `V`. A type is considered a subtype of itself, so they specify W ≠ V to count only proper subtypes.)

> For any element G of MEC that is a generic type:
>
> [lots of text]

MEC contains no generic types, so we can skip this.

> Let lub(U1 ... Uk) be:
>
> Best(W1) & ... & Best(Wr)
>
> where Wi (1 ≤ i ≤ r) are the elements of MEC, the minimal erased
>   candidate set of U1 ... Uk;
>
> and where, if any of these elements are generic, we use the candidate
>   parameterization (so as to recover type arguments):
>
> Best(X) = Candidate(X) if X is generic; X otherwise.

`Candidate` was defined in the part we skipped; we can still skip it, since it only matters for generic types.

lub(null, Double) is Best(Double), and Best(Double) is Double, so lub(null, Double) is Double.

Comment: Fantastic! I wasn't feeling that motivated to work out the definition!

Answer (score 3):

I believe that `lub(null, Double) === Double`. Not sure why use `lub(null, Double)`. Maybe to allow for change in the semantics of the *null type* in the future?

Here's my reasoning. By definition, `LUB = lub(T_1, ..., T_n)`, the Least Upper Bound of types T_1,...,T_n, is a type that is a supertype of all T_1, ..., T_n such that there's no proper subtype of `LUB` that is also a supertype of all T_1,...,T_n (ie, it's the *most specific* type that's simultaneously a supertype of `T_1,...,T_n`).

By definition, the type of the `null` expression is the *null type*. Also by definition, all reference types except the *null type* are direct supertypes of the *null type*.

`Double` is a supertype of the *null type*. `Double` is also a supertype of itself, the `Double` type. So `Double` does satisfies the condition *is a supertype of all `T_1,...,T_n`*. On the other hand, there's no other type that can be a proper subtype of `Double` and still be a supertype of `Double`. Hence, `Double` is the `lub(null, Double)`.