# NPE：cannot unbox null value

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
Boolean sortAsc = Objects.nonNull(chooseRequest) ? chooseRequest.getSortAsc() : false;
```

This code will throw NPE exception, why?

`chooseRequest` is a DTO and `chooseRequest.getSortAsc()` will return null

but this one is ok

```
Boolean sortAsc = Objects.nonNull(chooseRequest) ? null : false;
```

I cannot understand, JVM is 11

Comment: Format your code as code. Either indent 4 characters OR enclose with a set of three back-tick characters on lines above & below.

Comment: use `Boolean.FALSE` instead of `false`? (or `(Boolean)false`, less preferable) -- Java Language Specification [15.25.1. Boolean Conditional Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se22/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.1): "The type of a boolean conditional expression is determined as follows: * If the second and third operands are both of type Boolean, the conditional expression has type Boolean.  * Otherwise, the conditional expression has type boolean." and consequently `null` cannot be converted to `boolean`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have the expression

```
Objects.nonNull(chooseRequest)
    ? chooseRequest.getSortAsc()
    : false
```

and the return type of `chooseRequest.getSortAsc()` is defined as `Boolean`, then the "result" of this (boolean) conditional expression will be a `boolean` (the primitive type), as indicated in the table [Table 15.25-B. Conditional expression type (Primitive 3rd operand, Part II)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25-400-B):

> **Table 15.25-B. Conditional expression type (Primitive 3rd operand, Part II)**
>
> | 3rd → | [...] | boolean |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | **2nd ↓** |  |  |
> | [...] |  |  |
> | Boolean |  | boolean |

When `chooseRequest.getSortAsc()` is returning `null`, you will get a `NullPointerException` because it tries to call the `java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()` method on `null` to convert the `Boolean` value to a `boolean` value.

However, when you have the expression

```
Objects.nonNull(chooseRequest)
    ? null
    : false
```

then the "result" of this (reference) condition expression will be a `Boolean` (the wrapper class):

> **Table 15.25-B. Conditional expression type (Primitive 3rd operand, Part II)**
>
> | 3rd → | [...] | boolean |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | **2nd ↓** |  |  |
> | [...] |  |  |
> | null |  | lub(null,Boolean) |

*(for a definition of `lub()` see [4.10.4. Least Upper Bound](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.4). Also see [What is lub(null, Double)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43506017/what-is-lubnull-double))*

No `NullPointerException` will be thrown here because no method is called on `null`.

Overall, the `NullPointerException` is not coming from calling the `getSortAsc()` method on `null` as you might suspect, it's coming from a conversion of `null` to a `boolean` value. Interestingly, if you change your variable from `Boolean sortAsc` to `boolean sortAsc`, your second code block will throw a `NullPointerException` as well, since it tries to call `java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()` on the returned `null` value (assuming `Objects.nonNull(chooseRequest)` returned `true` at that time).