# Why does returning null for a primitive work in this case?

Tags: java, jls

This ugly piece of code does compile but throws NPE if `s == null`

```
public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String s)
{
    return s != null ? s.isEmpty() : null;
}
```

while this does not (as expected):

```
public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String s)
{
    if(s != null)
        return s.isEmpty();
    else
        return null;
}
```

I know both of them are plainly wrong, but as I found the first piece of code in our sources, I was quite surprised it did compile.

Edit:
Here's the relevant part of the JLS from Java 7. I guessed the first statement would apply but the bold one does.

**15.25 Conditional Operator ? :**

[...]

The type of a conditional expression is determined as follows:

[...]

- If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type T, and the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.

[...]

- **Otherwise, the second and third operands are of types S1 and S2 respectively. Let
  T1 be the type that results from applying boxing conversion to S1, and let T2 be
  the type that results from applying boxing conversion to S2.
  The type of the conditional expression is the result of applying capture
  conversion (§5.1.10) to lub(T1, T2) (§15.12.2.7).**

Comment: Same question with weird `return` style: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098953/tricky-ternary-operator-in-java-autoboxing

Comment: Thanks, that seems relevant.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**The first** has a ternary operator which has a result type of `Boolean`. The NPE is converting a `null` to a `boolean`.

It is actually something like:

```
Boolean temp = s != null ? s.isEmpty() : null; //no problems here
return temp; //crash when temp==null
```

**The second** is trying to return a wrong type (Object instead of primitive) - and thus does not compile.

Comment: What determines the return type of a ternary? If it's Boolean, it makes sense and autoboxing occures. If it's boolean, it shouldn't compile as the 2nd example. Am I wrong here?

Comment: @atamanroman: The type of the conditional is explained in [the specs 15.25](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25). I believe the last condition applies here: `Otherwise, the second and third operands are of types S1 and S2 respectively. Let T1 be the type that results from applying boxing conversion to S1, and let T2 be the type that results from applying boxing conversion to S2.  The type of the conditional expression is the result of applying capture conversion (§5.1.10) to lub(T1, T2) `

Comment: and you are mistaking about the 2nd example because `null` is not being unboxed to `boolean`, its *static type* is not `Boolean`. If you would have done `Boolean b = null; return b;` - you would get your NPE back instead of compile time error

Comment: So S1 And S2 are both boxed and the ternary returns Boolean with the value null which is unboxed and hence throws NPE? Seems weird but correct. I did not expect any boxing since I'm dealing with primitives only.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Tricky Ternary Operator in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098953/tricky-ternary-operator-in-java-autoboxing?lq=1)

The ternary operator does Autoboxing using rules as quoted in JLS:

[Boxing Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)

> This rule is necessary because the conditional operator (§15.25)
>   applies boxing conversion to the types of its operands, and uses the
>   result in further calculations.

**The problem is with the Autoboxing in Java. The problem is due to second operand not thrid.**

```
public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String s)
    {
        return s != null ? null : null;
    }
```

This code wont compile

[JLS for Conditional Operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)

Comment: maybe I am not totally clear in my answer but referring the JLS will surely help you.

Comment: `null` is NOT `Boolean`, thus applying boxing on `boolean` does not give you the 3rd operand. The case here is the last one (the last otherwise) as I commented to @atamanroman as a comment to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ternary Operator needs to find out the most appropriate return type for both operands.

Thus, it allows some "polish" of the return type.

*As showed in your first code snippet:*

```
public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String s)
{
    return s != null ? s.isEmpty() : null;
}
```

`s.empty()` returns primitive `boolean` whereas third operand returns `null`.
So the most specific common return type is `Boolean`. Compiler job is like replace the line by:

```
return s != null ? s.isEmpty() : (Boolean)null;
```

Return type method expects a `boolean` primitive, so the compiler says: "cool, I just have to unbox my result !". Unfortunately, `null` isn't unboxable and leads to an ugly NPE.

*With your second snippet:*

```
public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String s)
{
    if(s != null)
        return s.isEmpty();
    else
        return null;
}
```

No additional "polish" of pre-return type is made since compiler doesn't link both return statements in this code => might be a too hard job for it.

So, in this case, it is logical that the code doesn't even compile since `null` is NOT associated to `Boolean`! So, no kind of cast occurs.

To compile it, it should be written as:

```
public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String s)
    {
        if(s != null)
            return s.isEmpty();
        else
            return (Boolean)null;
    }
```

But does not prevent the famous NPE to occur while attempting to unbox ;)