# Weird crash with latest Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-dfp, google-analytics-firebase

I've just added the latest [Google Play Services 4.3](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2014/03/google-play-services-43.html) to my company's application, in order to use the integrated *Google Analytics SDK* and *DFP*.

Once into production, this **weird crash** started popping up.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null result when primitive expected
   at $Proxy3.equals()
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$g.equals()
   at java.util.ArrayList.contains(ArrayList.java:342)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ei.a()
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$h.b()
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$h.a()
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$b.ec()
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$a.handleMessage()
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

What is more, this crash seems to be very frequent. Does anyone know anything about this? Does it happen to you as well?

Should I submit an issue report?

---

**EDIT**: please, do not ask for code snippets. As you can see from the stack trace, it is not originated by a specific point of the app, but is rather coming from some inner code of the Play Services library.

Comment: I don't know (because of lack of your code) why it happens, but here is what happend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625956/why-does-returning-null-for-a-primitive-work-in-this-case

Comment: It is pointless to share the code because, as you can see from the stack trace, it is not originated by a specific point of my app but instead comes from inside the Play Services library. As for the error, I meant `weird` in the sense that it is inside the aforementioned library, not in the programmatic sense of it.

Comment: Then it is a GooglePlayServices severe bug, or something in your app is causing (even indirectly) this.

Comment: That's exactly what I would like to know. If I'm the only one experiencing it, it is probably an error on my side. If, on the other hand, more people start spotting it, it is likely to be a bug.

Comment: not sure what the bug is but a few things to check: Have you added the gmscore services version in manifest file? Are you calling any particular API before this crash happens? The stack does not relate to analytics so I would guess that removing analytics calls will still show the stack trace. right?

Comment: Yes, I have the Play Services version in my AndroidManifest (otherwise the application would crash immediately at startup). I am not able to reproduce the issue, so I have no idea if a particular API is causing the issue. Finally, since I cannot replicate the issue, I cannot be sure that it is a Analytics-related or a DPF-related issue.

Comment: Were you successfully in determining the source of this issue or how to fix it?

Comment: Since I stripped the Play Services library, I haven't been able to see this error again. I also wrote a related article on this subject: https://medium.com/@rotxed/28e6cb40cf71

Comment: @dextor Have you resolved your issue?

Comment: Yes, stripping the Play Services library as I mentioned above. If you're using Gradle, you can now rely on Play Services' more fine grained dependency management (http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html).