# Strange things in java

Tags: java, types, casting, double

Found some strange things in java.

Code:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
System.out.println((true) ? (int)2.5 : 3.5);
System.out.println((true) ? (int)2.5 : 3);
System.out.println((true) ? (int)2.5 + "" : 3.5);
```

Result:

```
1.8.0_40
2.0
2
2
```

What is it? Why integer value returns only if value for false is not a double or if string value added to value for true? Why in second line rounding works by (int) cast, but double value returns yet? Is it a bug?

Comment: No, these things are not bugs.

Comment: As far as the compiler is concerned, there is only one type for the whole `?:` expression, and it figures that out by finding the narrowest type in common between both sides.

Comment: (I confess I'm surprised that the last line compiles, though.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman I think it must be through auto-boxing.

Comment: Take note of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25230247/1743880) in the linked question about the same behaviour, with reference to the specification.

Answer (score 4):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25 specifies all these rules, which are behaving exactly consistently with your observed output.

There is only one type for the entire ternary expression, and that's what gets returned and that's what `System.out.println` is being called on.  If you look it up in the table in that specification, you'll find the types in the lines you've mentioned are going to be `double`, `int`, and `Object` respectively.

Answer (score 3):

In a schematic:

```
(true) ? (int)2.5 : 3.5

         int        double
           \        /
             double
```

The `double` literal 2.5 is downsampled to `int` 2, then promoted back to `double` 2.0 because that's the type of the conditional expression.

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator has a constant return type.

From the [JLS, section 15.25](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

> Otherwise, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is applied to the operand types, and the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the second and third operands.

This means that in `(true) ? (int)2.5 : 3.5`, `2.5` is converted to an `int`, (rounded down) then widened to a `double`.

In `(true) ? (int)2.5 : 3`, the `int` does not need to be widened to a `double`, because the other side is also an `int`.

Finally, in `(true) ? (int)2.5 + "" : 3.5);`, it *can't* be widened, because it's already been converted to a `String`.