# JAVA: Compiler error using ternary operator in method overload

Tags: java, methods, overloading, conditional-operator

```
String a = "bla";
byte[] b = new byte [10];

method (a != null ? a : b, b);
```

Why can't I use the above method call using ternary operator? Using if else statement works fine:

```
if (a != null) {
    method (a, b);
} else {
    method (b, b);
}
```

```
void method(String arg1, byte[] arg2) {
   // do something

void method (byte[] arg1, byte[] arg2) {
  // do something
}
```

I expected I could use the ternary operator in method overload. But a compiler error occours.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected type resulting from the ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230171/unexpected-type-resulting-from-the-ternary-operator)

Comment: You could if you had a method with `method(Object arg1, byte[] arg2)`. `String` and `byte[]` are completely different types, so what type should the expression `a != null ? a : b` have? Only `Object` is possible here.

Comment: The short answer is this: a ternary/conditional operator is not a 1-for-1 substitute for an if-else.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler needs to decide what the type of each expression is. java is a two-step process: First the compiler turns your java source code into bytecode, then the JVM runs that bytecode.

The key point is: Figuring out which method **overload** to call is done **by the compiler**. 2 methods with the same name but different param types? Those are 'overloads'. Those 2 methods you have, even though they have the same name, are **utterly unrelated** - in JVM terms a method's identity is the combination of its name, *and* its param types (but not its param names), *and* its return type.

`method(byte[], String)` and `method(String, String)` are thus as unrelated as `foo()` and `bar()` are: They are just.. completely different.

The **compilation phase** (`javac`) needs to figure out which of the two methods you intend. A method call as written in java source code translates to 1 `INVOKEVIRTUAL` bytecode instruction.

Hence, `method(x ? a : b, c)` does not work if `a` would lead you to one overload and `b` would lead to another - javac just doesn't work that way (why not? Well, at some point it's "Because the spec says so").

In bytecode terms:

```
method(x ? a : b, c)
```

is a string that `javac` parses and converts into bytecode. That bytecode looks roughly like this:

```
PUSH x        // x is now on the stack
CHECKBOOL +2  // pop the stack. Is it 'true'? Advance 10 instructions. Otherwise just continue
PUSH b
ADVANCE +1    // skip over next instruction
PUSH a
PUSH c
INVOKEVIRTUAL com.foo.YourClass method([BLjava/lang/String;)V
```

The crucial insight is that last one: That weird string is JVM-ese for 'a method located in `com.foo.YourClass`, named `method`, with 2 parameters, the first is a byte array (`[B`), the second is a string (`Ljava/lang/String:)`, which returns void `)V`. That WHOLE THING is the identity of the method. And the point is, `javac` must figure out what to put there, and in your ternary operator, there's nothing that fits - because depending on which way the operator goes, you want a completely different method.

Hence why it doesn't work. Now, javac *could* be updated so that it simply turns the java source code `method(x ? a : b, c)` into this bytecode:

```
PUSH x
CHECKBOOL +4
PUSH b
PUSH c
INVOKEVIRTUAL  com.foo.YourClass method([BLjava/lang/String;)V
ADVANCE +3
PUSH a
PUSH c
INVOKEVIRTUAL com.foo.YourClass method(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

i.e. generate both INVOKEVIRTUALS, but the spec says that java-the-language doesn't work that way.

This has some advantages. For example, in IDEs, you can CMD/CTRL+click on `method` in your line `method(x ? a : b, c)` and the IDE will then jump to the place where `method` is defined. If it worked like you thought, then.. which of the two `method` implementations should your editor hop to? It would have to show you a menu of all possible methods it could lead to and ask you to pick which one you wanted. That'd be fine too, but IDEs don't have to worry about this: Any single method name is necessarily linked to a single method definition.

### So what the heck is dynamic dispatch about, then?

That only applies when you have 2 methods whose identity is *the same*, but the methods are in different classes:

```
class Parent {
  byte foo(int[] x, boolean a) {}
}

class Child extends Parent {
  byte foo(int[] y, boolean b) {}
}
```

Here, both `foo` have an identical identity: It's both `foo([IZ])B` in JVM-speak. The compiler will encode that, but the runtime will figure out which of the various overrides to call. Thus, given:

```
Parent p = new Child();
p.foo(arg, arg)
```

The actual method invoked at runtime would be the `foo` that Child defines.

### The take-home

- Compiler decides which overload
- Runtime decides which override

overload = same method name, different parameter types/counts
override = same method name *and* parameter types/counts, but that method also exists in one of your supertypes.

### So break down in detail why the compiler fails here

`x ? a : b` is an expression that needs a type. If `a` is of type `byte[]` and `b` is of type `String`, as in your example, the compiler is forced to figure out **one single type** that fits in either scenario. In other words, some type that *both* `byte[]` as well as `String` are compatible with.

And byte[] and String share very little. So, it's `Object & Serializable`. Basically, just `Object` (let's not open the can of worms of `Serializable` here) - because that's the most specific shared parentage of String and byte[]. Thus, javac looks for a method whose signature is `method(Object, byte[])`, doesn't find one, and errors out.

In contrast, with your `if` based code construct, the first arg in each block is of type `byte[]` or `String` - so the compiler looks for `method(byte[], byte[])` and finds that, and in the `else` block, looks for `method(String, byte)`, also an existing thing, and compiles that. No errors.