# Ternary expression sometimes bypasses compiler checks validations

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, expression, ternary-operator

For some reason, the following code compiles normally:

```
public double getSomeDouble() {
    return "" != null ? 3.7d : null;
}
```

I would normally expect [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) to mark it as an error (`null` can not be turned to a `double` primitive).

Just to back my assumption, this code would not work:

```
public double getSomeDouble() {
    return null;
}
```

Eclipse would mark the `return null` line as error, stating:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from `null` to `double`

Why doesn't it say the same thing on the previous code snippet?!

Comment: [Related?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8098953/1391249)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's due to [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) and [autounboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8). If you look at the bytecode (below), you can see calls to `Double.valueOf` (boxing the `3.7d`) and `Double#doubleValue` (unboxing the result of the conditional expression). The operands to the conditional operator must be the same type, so the compiler is effectively turning your code into this:

```
public double getSomeDouble() {
    return ("" != null ? Double.valueOf(3.7d) : null).doubleValue();
}
```

...because `Double` is the most specific common type it can find for `3.7d` and `null`.

I used a string argument (to eliminate compiler optimization around the invariant expression `"" != null`, which the compiler would be able to tell would never be true):

```
public double getSomeDouble(String str) {
     return str != null ? 3.7d : null;
}
```

which effectively becomes:

```
public double getSomeDouble(String str) {
    return (str != null ? Double.valueOf(3.7d) : null).doubleValue();
}
```

...and indeed got an NPE at runtime when I passed in `null` for `str`, when it tried to call `doubleValue()` on `null`.

Here's the bytecode for my `getSomeDouble(String)` (from `javap -c MyClass`):

```
  public double getSomeDouble(java.lang.String);
    Code:
       0: aload_1
       1: ifnull        13
       4: ldc2_w        #7                  // double 3.7d
       7: invokestatic  #9                  // Method java/lang/Double.valueOf:(D)Ljava/lang/Double;
      10: goto          14
      13: aconst_null
      14: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/lang/Double.doubleValue:()D
      17: dreturn
```

Comment: Though the error reason is clear now, I still would like to setup eclipse compiler to track those for me not (in runtime that is too late :(), do you know of a way?

Comment: @MaximRahlis: I'm afraid I don't. Looks like Guillaume has found a feature request you might want to watch...

Comment: Thank you guys! Will certainly watch the eclipse feature request thread.