# Class Cast exception which seems to be a valid statement

Tags: java

```
System.out.println((long)(new Object()!=null ? 0 : new Object()));
```

On execution this gives a class cast exception as follows

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

This maybe a lame question but I'm not able to understand as to why this is happening even after we are explicitly casting the 0 returned to long.

Comment: you need to write `0L`, otherwise it is automaticly boxed as an `int`. Every number without a specification is therefore handelt to be an `int` (despite something like `0.0` which would be a `double`)

Comment: Additionally, as we are talking about objects, Integer can't be typecasted to Long

Comment: Each Long is an Object, not each Object is a Long.

Comment: @KevinEsche you should create an answer based on your comment.

Comment: @DaDaDom i am pretty sure this is a duplicate, but anyway you are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to assign an `int` to a `long` which results in a `ClassCastException`.

To get the correct result you will need to define the value `0` that you are trying to cast to a `long` as an actuall `long` value.

In that case every non floating number that you are trying to assign is actually handelt to be an `int` if you don´t explicity define the type of the value.

This can easily be seen if you just write `long i = 11111111111;`. Your compiler should tell you that the range for this number is out of the scope for an `int`. To tell the compiler that this value should be handelt as a long you simply need to add an `L` after the number: `long i = 11111111111L;`.

In your case your statement should be

```
System.out.println((long)(new Object()!=null ? 0L : new Object()));
```

Some additional information:

A similiar scenario happens with the `double` aswell. `float f = 0.;` wont work because you would need to define it as a float by adding a `F` after the value. `float f = 0.F;`

EDIT:

Your value `0` should get wrapped into `Integer` because it is possible that it could return an `Object`. if you write it as `System.out.println((long)(new Object()!=null ? 0 : 1));` this would compile again.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I am explicitly typecasting the int to long and AFAIK this is possible.

Comment: @SachinMalhotra you can´t cast an `Integer` to `Long`, aswell as you can´t cast a `Double` to be a `Float`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try using;

```
System.out.println((long)(new Object()!=null ? 0L : new Object()));
```

You are getting Exception because the ternary returns Integer 0 for true and that can't be cast to Long.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding on to what already has been told. According to java specifications for ternary operator,

***If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type T, and the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.***

Also a similar question to this one which is due to yet another rule for ternary operators.

[Similar tricky autoboxing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098953/tricky-ternary-operator-in-java-autoboxing)

Apologies for adding a duplicate question. :)