# Unwanted NullPointerException in ternary operator - Why?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, double, conditional-operator

While executing the following code, I am getting a `NullPointerException` at  line:

```
value = condition ? getDouble() : 1.0;
```

In earlier lines when I use `null` instead of `getDouble()` everything works and this is strange.

```
public class Test {
    static Double getDouble() {
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean condition = true;
        Double value;

        value = condition ? null : 1.0;         //works fine
        System.out.println(value);              //prints null

        value = condition ? getDouble() : 1.0;  //throws NPE
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Can someone help me understand this behavior?

Comment: What do you mean "change getDouble() to null"? The method already returns null in the code you posted.

Comment: This is the strange thing...If I change to null every thing works fine. Although method is returning null

Comment: When I say change to null means ...instead of calling the method which is returning null i used null directly

Comment: Possibly related: [Tricky ternary operator in Java - autoboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8098953)

Comment: I tried to simplify and at the same time clarify your example. If I misunderstood your intention feel free to rollback my edit.

Comment: this question appears to be derived from [JDK-8062801](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8062801)

Comment: And I think, Joker, you're a doppelganger of @Eran. Again: respect.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

When you write

```
value = condition ? null : 1.0;
```

the type of `condition ? null : 1.0` must be a reference type, so the type is `Double`, which can hold the value `null`.

When you write

```
value = condition ? getDouble() : 1.0;
```

and `getDouble()` returns `null`, it's equivalent to writing:

```
value = condition ? ((Double) null) : 1.0;
```

In this case the compiler sees a `Double` and a `double` as the 2nd and 3rd arguments of the ternary conditional operator, and decides that type of the expression should be `double`. Therefore it unboxes the `null` to `double`, getting `NullPointerException`.

The type of the conditional ternary operator is determined by some tables in [JLS 15.25](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25).

If the 2nd and 3rd operands are `null` and `double`, the conditional expression type is the least upper bound of `Double` and `null`, which is `Double`.

If the 2nd and 3rd operands are `Double` and `double`, the conditional expression type is `double`.

Comment: Weird. I'd file some kind of ticket against this. Even if the language standard says the compiler is supposed to pick `double`, this is a narrowing conversion since `double` doesn't support `null`. All other implicit narrowing conversions are avoided like the plague, if I recall correctly. I should think it ought to be changed for consistency.

Comment: based on the answer above ...you can change it to the following and  it will work fine `value = condition ? getDouble() : new Double(1.0);`

Comment: Why would someone know that?

Answer (score 26):

See [#jls-15.25](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

[image]

If the 2nd operand is `Double`, while the 3rd operand is  `double`, the result:

`getCount() == 1 ? getDouble() : 1.0`

will be a `double`.

And when you try to convert a `Double null`(returned by `getDouble()`) to `double`, `NPE` will be thrown.

Comment: And further on JLS: 15.25.2 says: "If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type `T`, and the type of the
other is the result of applying boxing conversion to `T`, then the type of
the conditional expression is `T`." The boxing fails with a NPE.