# Unwanted Null Pointer Exception in ternary operator with Optional

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

To my understanding following code should not throw `Null Pointer exception` as I am safely using Optional interface.

However, when I ran this code it is throwing `NPE`.

```
public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            final Integer inte = false ? 0 : Optional.ofNullable((Integer) null).orElse(null);
         }
    }
```

Please let me know if I am mistaken somewhere in my code and help me to rectify the same.

Comment: Why are you casting null to an Integer? Try to write just null.

Comment: Why are you using an Optional if you're just going to do `orElse(null)` making it null when the Optional is empty?

Comment: This is not clear and this code will not even compile. Are you assigning it to a variable of type `Integer` or `int` ?

Comment: @michalk  Before commenting , did you try to compile it

Comment: @JohnStringer - Question is not why I am doing that , it is why it is behaving like this ?

Comment: @Joker then my answer is it won't throw an NPE. The code above won't compile because you've tried to call your Integer `int`, `int` being a language keyword means it doesn't work as a variable name...

Comment: @Joker I could ask the same question to you. Do you think `int` is valid name for a variable in Java when it is a keyword that represents a primitive type?

Comment: And now after your edit - this code will not throw NPE...

Comment: Guys that was typo, I think u were questioning the logic compilation.

Comment: Respect, Joker. Do you create riddles like this one on purpose? And re-post them [once a year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52147247/getting-unwanted-nullpointerexception-in-ternary-operator-why)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting unwanted NullPointerException in ternary operator - Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52147247/getting-unwanted-nullpointerexception-in-ternary-operator-why)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason you get a NullPointerException, is that the type of the expression `false ? 0 : Optional.ofNullable((Integer) null).orElse(null)` is `int` (by [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) Table 15.25-C).

The expression `Optional.ofNullable((Integer) null).orElse(null)` evaluates to `null`, and casting a `null` to an `int` results in a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you'll get a NullPointerException, because your right hand side is just a very verboose way of saying `null`. You're wrapping a `null` in an `Optional` thus forcing the `orElse` which executes to `null`.

Having `null` in a statement that resolves to `int`, as explained by @Hoopje (even if it's assigned to an `Integer` variable) leads to a `NullPointerException`.

Just wrapping `null` in an `Optional` still gives you a `null` when unwrapping it again.

Comment: The author is assigning `null` to an `Integer` reference. I hope that clears the ask.

Answer (score 0):

I found the work around

```
 final Integer inte = false ? (Integer)0 : Optional.<Integer>ofNullable(null).orElse(null);
```

or

```
final Integer inte = false ? (Integer)0 : Optional.ofNullable((Integer)null).orElse(null);
```

the type returned by the ternary operator is expected to be int (because of the literal 0).

Comment: Actually, I did test this and it makes sense. Also, about ternary operator :"Ternary operator returns a value or expression included in the second or third part of it. It does not execute the statements."  So in this case, the else part of the ternary operator was returning null, but the return type had been evaluated by the compiler to be int, instead of Integer. NPE was thrown because and int null was being returned, which is not possible. With the type casting of 0 to Integer, the returning value became Integer null, which is possible and that is what is happening.

Comment: Respect, Joker. Do you create riddles like this one on purpose? And re-post them [once a year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52147247/getting-unwanted-nullpointerexception-in-ternary-operator-why)?